# Middleman sprockets fingerprint

Tags: sprockets, middleman

I'm using middleman with sprockets for packaging my js and css files into one file. This works fine. But I was wondering if it is possible to enable the fingerprint feature from sprockets in middleman.

e.g. my file `all.js`, in which everything gets compiled, gets renamed to `all-4e17d33ff76d744900c2691a71ed83e4.js`.

It would also be great, if this would be possible with images.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't found a out of the box solution for this, but I made my own solution. In the `config.rb` I'm running the `after_build` hook. Not the best way, but it works:

```
after_build do
  require 'fileutils'
  delete_except "build/javascripts/", "all.js"
  delete_except "build/stylesheets/", "all.css"

  require 'digest/sha1'
  sha1 = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest Time.now.getutc.to_i.to_s
  allJS = "all-" + sha1 + ".js"
  allCSS = "all-" + sha1 + ".css"
  File.rename("build/javascripts/all.js", "build/javascripts/" + allJS)
  File.rename("build/stylesheets/all.css", "build/stylesheets/" + allCSS)

  index_file = "build/index.html"
  html = File.read(index_file)
  html = html.gsub(/all\.js/, allJS)
  html = html.gsub(/all\.css/, allCSS)

  File.open(index_file, "w") { |file| file.puts html }
end
```

I'm doing the following:

- delete unnecessary generated .js and .css files
- generating a sha1 hash based on time (that's enough for me)
- appending the hash to the files
- updating the `index.html` with the new file names

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
activate :asset_hash
```

in your Middleman config ([Improving Cacheability](http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/improving-cacheability/)).

(You'll want to use **either** `:asset_hash` or  `:cache_buster`, not both.)